# node webkit render gif files and animation in gpu

Tags: animation, optimization, gpu, gif, node-webkit

We have project written on node webkit which uses lot of gif animated files, when we run the app the load of CPU raises up to 100%, 
Is there any way to pass that work (rendering of gif files) to GPU instead of CPU, we have tried to enable GPU as described here   http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/ , but no result.

Comment: It doesn't sound like a good use of GPU. LZW decompression can't be broken up into threads or SIMD optimized. The majority of the time is spent decoding variable length codes and writing them to memory.

Comment: thanks for comment :) so what can I do to optimize gif animations in node web kit app, is there any other way to create animations without gif

Comment: You can use CSS sprites, and animate them with JS or CSS animations. Btw. have you found a solution for this question? :)